# Upload file to google drive on specific folder with progress bar and python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, google-drive-api

This is my code for uploading to google drive with python requests without using google-drive-api:

```py
import os
import sys
import json
import requests
import collections
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests_toolbelt
from requests.exceptions import JSONDecodeError

class ProgressBar(tqdm):
    def update_to(self, n: int) -> None:
        self.update(n - self.n)

def upload_file(access_token:str, filename:str, filedirectory:str, folder_id: str):

    metadata = {
        "name": filename,
        "parents": [{"id": folder_id}]
    }

    session = requests.session()

    with open(filedirectory, "rb") as fp:
        files = collections.OrderedDict(data=("metadata", json.dumps(metadata), "application/json"), file=fp)
        encoder = requests_toolbelt.MultipartEncoder(files)
        with ProgressBar(
            total=encoder.len,
            unit="B",
            unit_scale=True,
            unit_divisor=1024,
            miniters=1,
            file=sys.stdout,
        ) as bar:
            monitor = requests_toolbelt.MultipartEncoderMonitor(
                encoder, lambda monitor: bar.update_to(monitor.bytes_read)
            )

            r = session.post(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
                data=monitor,
                allow_redirects=False,
                json=metadata,
                headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Content-Type": monitor.content_type},
            )

    try:
        resp = r.json()
        print(resp)
    except JSONDecodeError:
        sys.exit(r.text)

upload_file(access_token, filename, filedirectory, "12345asdfghj")
```

But the above code is not uploading any file to a specific folder. I also tried some changes but nothing worked. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the endpoint of `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart`, I confirmed that you have used Drive API v3. In this case, please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
metadata = {
    "name": filename,
    "parents": [{"id": folder_id}]
}
```

#### To:

```
metadata = {
    "name": filename,
    "parents": [folder_id]
}
```

- `"parents": [{"id": folder_id}]` is for Drive API v2.

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create)